# JavaFX BufferOverflowException on embedded device

Tags: java, kotlin, javafx-8, embedded-linux, tornadofx

We're using a iMX6 SoM chip and a 480x272 LVDS display for our application.

We're also using Gluon's OpenJFX and an embedded build of Java 8u241.

Whenever we launch the `jar` file, we get spammed with the following errors

```
java.nio.BufferOverflowException
    at java.nio.DirectIntBufferU.put(DirectIntBufferU.java:363)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.UploadingPainter.run(UploadingPainter.java:153)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.RenderJob.run(RenderJob.java:58)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)Setting up UI took 127 ms
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:125)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Well I've been looking around the internet, but the only connection to the same error I saw, was the one with Monocle. We're not using it, but I've resized the app to 479x271, to see if the errors might vanish, but they persisted.

Now I'm running out of ideas to try.

Answer (score 2):

I've fixed it!

So, the problem was that a button was outside of the window's border(for a pixel), and it was resizing the window outside the framebuffer size.

I just moved the button up for a pixel and it runs flawlessly now.